# How do I convert a gradle project to android project

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

I use Eclipse ADT and i have convert my android project to gradle project through configure -> convert to gradle project, actually i need to convert my gradle project to android project. How i can do that  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Android project in Eclipse ADT usually should have 2 files

`.project`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>Android-app</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

`.classpath`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Once you correct them, your project is back standard Android project in Eclipse.

To use newer build system from Eclipse try [Nodeclipse/Enide Gradle for Eclipse](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.enide.gradle)
([marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle))

Some screenshots for Gradle for Eclipse:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**1.If project is created in eclipse**

You don't need to convert it to an Eclipse project, because its already an eclipse compatible project. You just need to re-import the project into yo
your workspace and it should work fine.

Note: There will be files specific to gradle project like build.gradle, etc. (you can delete if you want to).

**2.Created in gradle environment**

But if you have created the project in gradle directly:

Usually it is a simple as adding `apply plugin: "eclipse"` in your `build.gradle` and running

```
cd myProject/
gradle eclipse
```

and then refreshing your Eclipse project.

Occasionally you'll need to adjust build.gradle to generate Eclipse settings in some very specific way.

There is [gradle support for Eclipse](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/blob/master/README.md) if you are using STS, but I'm not sure how good it is.

The only IDE I know that has decent native support for gradle is [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). It can do full import of gradle projects from GUI. There is a free Community Edition that you can try.