# How to use scissors library in Eclipse ADT?

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to use this library for image cropping but I don't know how to include it in an Eclipse project?

https://github.com/lyft/scissors

Can I just copy-paste the classes in some folder or is that against the license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've convert this lib into Eclipse compatible project.
Download it from [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DFA0AB99C8A60DA5!1247&authkey=!AKLd3lsL7DZuFTE&ithint=file%2Czip).
for integrating it into eclipse follow these step:

1. Unzip file.
2. Import into eclipse.
3. Mark Project as library project.
4. Make sure you are using `support library` version `22.2.1` or higher from `Android SDK Manager`. If not update it.
5. Copy `android-support-v4` JAR into `libs` folder from `appcompat_v7` Project (I guess).

Now you're ready to go. Just add this project as library into your desire project.

Comment: It's really hard. I suggest that stop using Eclipse ADT.

Answer (score 1):

Start using Android studio, Google has already stopped support for Eclipse (ADT), so it would be better for you to start emphasising on Android studio.

The Github project mentioned is Gradle based, you can either use Eclipse or Android studio to import the project.

Android Studio - You can mention the project's dependancy i.e. `compile 'com.lyft:scissors:1.0.3'`
in your build.grade and you are good to go.

[Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22866608/6012797)